# Android Gradle Plugin 8.0.0 with Kotlin 1.8.20 causes OkHttp3 R8 minify problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-r8

After upgrading to Kotlin 1.8.20 with Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 8.0.0, I suddendly get the following error messages when running the `:app:minifyProdWithR8` Gradle task :

```
Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLSocket (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 5 other contexts)
Missing class org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.BouncyCastlePlatform.<init>())
Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt$Version (referenced from: boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int))
Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt (referenced from: boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int) and 4 other contexts)
Missing class org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier (referenced from: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$DisabledHostnameVerifier)
Missing class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List))
Missing class org.openjsse.javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.configureTlsExtensions(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket, java.lang.String, java.util.List) and 1 other context)
Missing class org.openjsse.net.ssl.OpenJSSE (referenced from: void okhttp3.internal.platform.OpenJSSEPlatform.<init>())
Missing class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder (referenced from: void org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind() and 3 other contexts)
```

I have the Ktor client library `io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.2.4` in my project which probably depends on okhttp3 and the other missing classes. Has anyone else experience that problem?

Just adding exclusion rules to the `proguard-rules.pro` doesn't seem right to me at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I could solve the problem by myself. For anyone else facing this problem. Here is the workaround I am using now:

Based on the following [dicussion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-5528/Missing-class-warning-when-using-R8-with-ktor-client-in-android-application) and this [pull request](https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/9da841c24c3b3dabc1d9230ab2f1e71105768771) on the OkHttp Library itself, I added the following rules to my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.openjsse.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
```

Answer (score 0):

These messages where probably warnings before upgrading to AGP 8.0.0. From 7.0.0 warnings for missing classes where added, and the plan to make them errors was [announced](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-7-0-0-release-notes#r8-missing-class-warning).

Also see https://issuetracker.google.com/278765639, where this issue was reported.

The file `app/build/outputs/mapping/release/missing_rules.txt` is generated by AGP with the `-dontwarn` directives required to avoid the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in your Gradle file :

```
  packagingOptions {
        resources {
            META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro
               }
```

after that try to build a release version
also, go to **app/build/outputs/mapping**
and add all of the lines with -dontwarn in proguard file

for me was below lines :

```
-dontwarn java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
-dontwarn java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
```

- I used okhttp logging version 5.0.0-alpha.11